# Wrapping block of code in ruby Thread object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, metaprogramming

we need to implement in our gem feature that needs to inject piece of code into Thread.new block statement globally. Let's leave here discussion about why :)

If I define something like:

```
module MyThread 

    def new(*args, &block)
        puts "i'm in Thread.new"
        super(*args, &block)
    end

end

Thread.singleton_class.prepend MyThread
```

and than create:

```
t = Thread.new {
    puts "I'm async thread"
}
t.join
```

I will see both put messages. Thing is I need to pass something from main thread to new thread so in such scenario I would need to modify block with is problematic. Without that even if I put something to MyThread.new it will be executed in main thread only. Normally I can reverse engineer such things by reading ruby code but Thread isn't defined in ruby, it's pure C api without any wrapper in ruby as I see.

So the question is if there is any option to pass something from main thread to new thread globally and define in new thread code that will wrap block there. Probably not without really dirty hacks, but maybe I'm missing something.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show a *specific* example of what exactly you want to achieve? Right now, your description is quite vague. How exactly do you want to pass data? What kind of data, and from where? How do you want to use this data and in what context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the code "injected" by your module runs in the main thread: (I've simplified your code slightly to patch `#initialize` rather than `.new`)

```
module MyThread
  def initialize(*args, &block)
    puts "Module is #{Thread.current}"
    super(*args, &block)
  end
end
Thread.prepend MyThread

puts "  Main is #{Thread.current}"
Thread.new { puts " Block is #{Thread.current}" }.join
```

Output:

```
  Main is #<Thread:0x00007f88e807bc78 run>
Module is #<Thread:0x00007f88e807bc78 run>
 Block is #<Thread:0x00007f88e20cc7c8 test.rb:10 run>
```

... but you want it to run in the other thread, just like the block.

To do so, you have to move it into the block you pass to `super`. Since you cannot modify the `block` argument, you have to create a new block and call the passed block from within:

```
module MyThread
  def initialize(*args, &block)
    super(*args) do |*inner_args|
      puts "Module is #{Thread.current}"
      block.call(*inner_args)
    end
  end
end
Thread.prepend MyThread

puts "  Main is #{Thread.current}"
Thread.new { puts " Block is #{Thread.current}" }.join
```

Output:

```
  Main is #<Thread:0x00007f927907bc88 run>
Module is #<Thread:0x00007f926203fb50 test.rb:3 run>
 Block is #<Thread:0x00007f926203fb50 test.rb:3 run>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this in a moment

Comment: I was running for second approach from your answer. Thank you. Works like a charm!